# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: User(#35560) expected, got ... which is an instance of User(#22700)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I've been getting intermittent errors while seeding with rails. I'm hoping someone can help provide some insight into the different types of the User class.

The error in full:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: User(#35560) expected, got #<User id: "bedc7c4e-cdd2-4ea1-a7ee-4e6642467fba", email: "phil@email.domain", jti: "7376cf41-7f88-407d-8365-1e311d946b88", ios_device_token: nil, fcm_device_token: nil, first_name: "Phil", last_name: "6", phone_number: nil, date_of_birth: nil, super_user: true, created_at: "2023-02-08 08:16:37.559974000 +0000", updated_at: "2023-02-08 08:16:37.559974000 +0000"> which is an instance of User(#22700)
```

The code which causes it:

```rb
  user = User.new(
    first_name: 'Phil',
    last_name: '6',
    email: 'phil@email.domain',
    super_user: true,
    password: 'test1234'
  )
  user.skip_confirmation!
  user.save!

  organisation = Organisation.find_by_name('Team')
  Membership.create!(
    user:,
    organisation:,
    verified: true,
    verified_at: now,
    organisation_admin: true,
    shift_admin: true,
    email: 'phil.6@group.com',
    email_confirmed: true,
    category: organisation.categories.find_by_name('Developer')
  )

  organisation = Organisation.find_by_name('Test Org')
  membership = Membership.create!(
    user:,
    organisation:,
    verified: true,
    verified_at: now,
    email: 'phil@testorg.com',
    email_confirmed: true
  )
```

If I pause execution before the error I can see that `user == User.first` is false despite `User.first` and `user` being these two lines, which are visually identical:

```
#<User id: "6ce62b08-cf4c-4bfa-878a-02a1ed889c69", email: "phil@email.domain", jti: "710948b6-5f4f-40ea-ab9f-df8e3b1219c3", ios_device_token: nil, fcm_device_token: nil, first_name: "Phil", last_name: "6", phone_number: nil, date_of_birth: nil, super_user: true, created_at: "2023-02-08 08:17:06.024800000 +0000", updated_at: "2023-02-08 08:17:06.024800000 +0000">
#<User id: "6ce62b08-cf4c-4bfa-878a-02a1ed889c69", email: "phil@email.domain", jti: "710948b6-5f4f-40ea-ab9f-df8e3b1219c3", ios_device_token: nil, fcm_device_token: nil, first_name: "Phil", last_name: "6", phone_number: nil, date_of_birth: nil, super_user: true, created_at: "2023-02-08 08:17:06.024800000 +0000", updated_at: "2023-02-08 08:17:06.024800000 +0000">
```

It's the same thing if I compare `user.class` and `User.first.class`, they look the same but a comparison evaluates to false.

Am I doing something to mutate the local variable?

Comment: I'm suprised that you're not getting a syntax error at `user:,`.

Comment: Ruby 3.1 introduced a new shorthand. https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/3.1.html#values-in-hash-literals-and-keyword-arguments-can-be-omitted

`user:,` is shorthand for `user: user,`

Comment: I'm still confused as to why you would want to explicitly pass nil for those keys.

Answer (score 1):

What you should be doing here is to create an assocation:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
end
```

Then you create the memberships through that assocation instead:

```
 user = User.create!(
    first_name: 'Phil',
    last_name: '6',
    email: 'phil@email.domain',
    super_user: true,
    password: 'test1234',
    confirmed_at: Time.current # the easy way to skip Devise::Confirmable
  )

  # make sure you use the bang method so that you're not just getting a nil
  organisation = Organisation.find_by_name!('Test Org') 

  user.memberships.create!(
    organisation: organisation,
    verified: true,
    verified_at: now,
    organisation_admin: true,
    shift_admin: true,
    email: 'phil.6@group.com',
    email_confirmed: true,
    category: organisation.categories.find_by_name!('Developer')
  )
```

Comment: This works! Thanks. I already had the relationship but wasn't using it. 

`confirmed_at: Time.current` is a great addition too, thank you.


I'm still curious about the type mismatch

Comment: It is kind of puzzling. If I had to take a wild guess it could be some sort of strange code reloading bug. Zeitwerk can reload constants on the fly so you can potentially have two users but the class is actually two different instances of Class. Thats normally something you would only see in the console though and not in a seed file.